# Database design for recursive children

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2007

This design problem is turning out to be a bit more "interesting" than I'd expected....

For context, I'll be implementing whatever solution I derive in Access 2007 (not much choice--customer requirement. I *might* be able to talk them into a different back end, but the front end has to be Access (and therefore VBA & Access SQL)). The two major activities that I anticipate around these tables are batch importing new structures from flat files and reporting on the structures (with full recursion of the entire structure). Virtually no deletes or updates (aside from entire trees getting marked as inactive when a new version is created).

I'm dealing with two main tables, and wondering if I really have a handle on how to relate them: Products and Parts (there are some others, but they're quite straightforward by comparison).

Products are made up of Parts. A Part can be used in more than one Product, and most Products employ more than one Part. I think that a normal many-to-many resolution table can satisfy this requirement (mostly--I'll revisit this in a minute). I'll call this Product-Part.

The "fun" part is that many Parts are also made up of Parts. Once again, a given Part may be used in more than one parent Part (even within a single Product). Not only that, I think that I have to treat the number of recursion levels as effectively arbitrary.

I can capture the relations with a m-to-m resolution from Parts back to Parts, relating each non-root Part to its immediate parent part, but I have the sneaking suspicion that I may be setting myself up for grief if I stop there. I'll call this Part-Part. Several questions occur to me:

1. Am I borrowing trouble by wondering about this? In other words, should I just implement the two resolution tables as outlined above, and stop worrying?
2. Should I also create Part-Part rows for all the ancestors of each non-root Part, with an extra column in the table to store the number of generations?
3. Should Product-Part contain rows for every Part in the Product, or just the root Parts? If it's all Parts, would a generation indicator be useful?
4. I have (just today, from the Related Questions), taken a look at the Nested Set design approach. It looks like it could simplify some of the requirements (particularly on the reporting side), but thinking about generating the tree during the import of hundreds (occasionally thousands) of Parts in a Product import is giving me nightmares before I even get to sleep. Am I better off biting that bullet and going forward this way?

In addition to the specific questions above, I'd appreciate any other comentary on the structural design, as well as hints on how to process this, either inbound or outbound (though I'm afraid I *can't* entertain suggestions of changing the language/DBMS environment).

Comment: Recursive children should be spanked.

Comment: Have you googled "access bill of materials"?

Comment: No, I hadn't tried Google. Now that I have, I found a few interesting things (may or may not be directly applicable), and a whole lot of listings for commercial software. The latter does me not good whatsoever....

Comment: There should be lots of links to BOM implementations in Access. It's been a FAQ in the Access Usenet groups for as long as I've been posting there (since 1996).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bills of materials and exploded parts lists are always so much fun. I would implement Parts as your main table, with a Boolean field to say a part is "sellable". This removes the first-level recursion difference and the redundancy of Parts that are themselves Products. Then, implement Products as a view of Parts that are sellable.

You're on the right track with the PartPart cross-ref table. Implement a constraint on that table that says the parent Part and the child Part cannot be the same Part ID, to save yourself some headaches with infinite recursion.

Generational differences between BOMs can be maintained by creating a new Part at the level of the actual change, and in any higher levels in which the change must be accomodated (if you want to say that this new Part, as part of its parent hierarchy, results in a new Product). Then update the reference tree of any Part levels that weren't revised in this generational change (to maintain Parts and Products that should not change generationally if a child does). To avoid orphans (unreferenced Parts records that are unreachable from the top level), Parts can reference their predecessor directly, creating a linked list of ancestors.

This is a very complex web, to be sure; persisting tree-like structures of similarly-represented objects usually are. But, if you're smart about implementing constraints to enforce referential integrity and avoid infinite recursion, I think it'll be manageable.

Comment: Products--even the one that consists of only one Part--have a different numbering scheme than Parts, _and_ they're used elsewhere in the "straightforward" areas I didn't talk about. Nice thought, though....

Answer (score 0):

I would have one part table for atomic parts, then a superpart table with a superpartID and its related subparts.  Then you can have a product/superpart table.
If a part is also a superpart, then you just have one row for the superpartID with the same partID.

Maybe 'component' is a better term than superpart.  Components could be reused in larger components, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can find sample Bill of Materials database schemas  at

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/

The website offers Access applications for some of the models.  Check with the author of the website.

Comment: That looks like a really useful site generally, but the BoM design looks a little too simple for my needs (direct self-join in the Product Hierarchy assumes that components are only used in one assembly). Thanks for the link.

Comment: Roger.  I didn't check the BoM in detail.