# Excel 2007 workbook locked after access from Access 2007

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I've got a project where I'm reading data from an Excel worksheet and saving it in Access tables (**not** a direct import--see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047320/database-design-for-recursive-children) if you're interested). My current problem is that any time I run my "import" and then try to open the workbook in Excel, it's "locked for editing" unless/until I close Access. I don't *think* this should be the case. My process is

1. Open the workbook with Automation.
2. Build a collection of sheet names.
3. Release the Automation objects.
4. If there's more than one sheet, get user input on which to process.
5. Open an ADO recordset on a specific range & read some data.
6. Release the recordset & connection.
7. Open an ADO recordset on a different specific range & read a bunch o' data.
8. Release the recordset & connection.
9. Close the controling form.

Steps 1 - 4 and 9 live in the form file, the remainder in a module.

Am I missing something? I *think* I've released all the references to the workbook....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your step #1 includes something like this:

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
```

And later releasing the object is this:

```
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Trying including this line just before you set the object variable to Nothing:

```
objExcel.Quit
```

It also helps to make the Excel application instance visible after starting it so you're less likely to leave Excel running unseen:

```
objExcel.Visible = True
```